# iOS6, Application receives SIGSTOP if installed from Cydia

Tags: ios, ios6, jailbreak, cydia

I have an application that can be installed in two forms: .ipa file and a Cydia package. It works well on iOS5. But on iOS6 a strange thing is happening, when the app was installed from Cydia. When I press the **Home** button, iOS sends `SIGSTOP` and the app is terminated. I don't have `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` set to `TRUE` in Info.plist. Any ideas why it's happening and how to prevent this?

Also on iOS6, it became possible to delete a Cydia app from SpringBoard, which does not look like a good feature, because the app in Cydia is still shown as *installed*. Is there any flag to avoid this?

EDIT:

I found that my app was killed because of strange deadlock and crash report was not generated because device had too much crash dumps on filesystem (I found this in console log). After deleting few logs from FS, I came to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164548/cocos2d-x-example-app-crashes-when-pressing-home. I'm not using cocos2d, but seems problem with OpenGL subsystem. It crashes even it's just initialised and not rendering anything. I was trying to call `glFinish()`, unload shader programs and `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil]`, but all of these do not help.

EDIT:

I solved this by full release of my rendering subsystem including OpenGL context when app is deactivated. Fortunately it was easy to do.